# Should the backingfile and descriptorfile created by bigmemory by checked into version control?

Tags: r, gitignore, r-bigmemory

I'm wondering what the best practices are for handling the *descriptorfile* (`foo.desc`) and *backingfile* (`foo.bin`) that are created when reading `foo.csv` using [`read.big.matrix(...)`](http://%20https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigmemory/versions/4.5.33/topics/write.big.matrix)

As far as I can find out the *backingfile* is an RDS file by default, and the *descriptorfile* is a plain text file. So in theory those are both cross-platform and could be checked in, but my guess is that the *backingfile* will change a lot and should be ignored by version control. Does anyone have experience here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backingfile is not an RDS file. It is just a simple binary file and should be cross-platform.

It is generally not recommended to version binary files, because they change a lot. Moreover, this is a large file and so it's even less recommended.

The descriptor file is useless by itself.

So, I would recommend to not version those files.
The only case would if it's only small files that you use for examples (see e.g. https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr/tree/master/inst/extdata).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.